# C/C++ huge header/source

Tags: c++, c, header

In my C project, I am reading data from an obj file and an image file for opengl. All the data is combined into 1 header file.

Example (psuedo code):

```
vertices = {
 0 , 2, 4,
 ....
};

normals = {
 0, 0, 0, 
 ....
};

texture_pixels = {
 0, 0, 0
...
}
```

The thing is that all this data adds up to a 15mb header. Is it a bad idea to have this massive header? Will this cause any issues in my program?

Comment: If the header file is subject to manual editing (as opposed to generated fully automatically by a build script) then this is guaranteed to become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether having a big header file vs. other approaches depends on the application.

The header file is processed at compile time.  If the file is infrequently compiled, or its compilation time is quick enough to be acceptable, there is no problem.

If the header file is frequently updated (say like more than once per day) even in its deployed configuration, perhaps the program could be rearchitected to read the equivalent data from a data file from the network, SD card, disk, or what-have-you.

Data files have their own weaknesses:

- They are a separate piece apart from the program executable which may need to be kept in sync.
- The file format is subject to big vs. little endian issues, unless it is coded in some character format (like XML).
- How should the program find the data?  Command line parameter, hard coded path, etc.
- If the file cannot be found, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you declare types and function prototypes in headers. and the only function bodies should be inline functions or static functions.

Header files are combined in the source during pre-processing. it is means the large header file will be combined to any source file who is including it.

it is not the right thing to declare variables in a header files. if you declare variable in the headers and include it from several source file, you'll get the "already defined" link error, exactly as if you declare 2 global variables with the same name.

if the header file is included only once than it is exactly like to put it in the source file.
but in any other case the large data should be located in a source file, and the header should contain only the `extern` declaration of the variables.

The compilation time for a source file depends it size after pre-processing. therefore if you reduce the file size by exporting parts to headers you won't improve the compilation time. if you divide it to several source files any part will be compiled separately, it slow down the compilation by a bit, but when you change one part, other parts won't be needed to recompile so sometimes it is better.